# Adding arraylist to custom listview

Tags: java, android

I have made a custom `ListView`. I'm trying to populate the `ListView` by `Arraylist`. I can successfully send data as a string to populate the `ListView` but not as `ArrayList`. Only single row with all the values of `arraylist` is being displayed.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
Adapter listviewAdapter;
List arrlist = new ArrayList();  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arrlist.add("1");
    arrlist.add("2");

    fillData();   
    listviewAdapter = new Adapter(this, products);
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    lvMain.setAdapter(listviewAdapter);
  }
  void fillData() {
      products.add(new Product(arrlist.toString(),false)); //problem is here i suppose

  }
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Product> objects;
Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = products;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }
    Product p = getProduct(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
    CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
    return view;
}
Product getProduct(int position) {
    return ((Product) getItem(position));
}
}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {
String name;
boolean selected;

  Product( String items, boolean _box) {
      name = items;
      selected = _box;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any exception you are getting?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Only single row with combined arraylist is being displayed

Comment: You passed all `arrlist.toString()` wooooooo! check your Argument of `Product`  class then.....

Comment: removed `.toString();` from `arrlist.toString()` and made changes to `Product` class i.e `List name;
 boolean selected;
      Product( List items, boolean _box) {
       name = items;
          selected = _box;
      }`  Still doesnt solves it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add each `ArrayList` item to `Product` object through iterating `ArrayList` :

```
for(String row :arrlist) {
    products.add(new Product(row, false));
}
```

Define arrlist as `String` `ArrayList` instead of generic type `List`:

```
ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Won't be a type mismatch? From object to string?

Comment: @Ted,Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be

```
void fillData() {
  products.add(new Product("1",false));
  products.add(new Product("2",false));
  products.add(new Product("3",false));
}
```

Comment: I know sending string works. This works. But my question is sending `arraylist` containing previous data